# Call knockout view model from element without data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using a CMS's API to add an HTML date picker element to a page but it doesn't allow me to add a arbitrary attributes to the outer element, so I can't set a data-bind for onclick.

However it does allow me to set an onchange Javascript callback when the date is changed and I was wondering if its possible to use this callback to interact with my Knockout view model.

Basically, I get some HTML rendered which, much simplified looks like this.

```
<div id="my-calendar">
    <!-- calendar stuff is rendered here -->
</div>
```

When the calendar date changes I can have arbitrary code executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can always obtain a reference to your view model by using the `ko.dataFor` method. It is a bit hidden in the docs but you can read about it on the page ["Using unobtrusive event handlers"](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html):

> [...] Knockout provides two helper functions that allow
>   you to identify the data associated with a DOM element:
>
> - ko.dataFor(element) - returns the data that was available for binding against the element
> - ko.contextFor(element) - returns the entire binding context that was available to the DOM element.

The method accepts a DOM element. If you give it the DOM element you bound your view model on then you get your view model in return. You can also give it the DOM e.g. of a Knockout component and you will get the component's view model.